# Multithreaded PowerShell Script

Tags: multithreading, powershell, csv

i made a PowerShell script that takes data from a CSV File, sorts that data and creates a new CSV file.

The File is around 50mb, which makes my script painfully slow.

I want to make my Script Multithreading compatible, but im having trouble with the Start-Job -Script block command.

The new file will not be created if i use this command.

Can you see my mistake in the script?

Thanks for your help!

```
    [CmdletBinding(DefaultParameterSetName='Parameter Set 1',
SupportsShouldProcess=$true,
PositionalBinding=$false,
HelpUri = 'http://www.microsoft.com/',
ConfirmImpact='Medium')]
[Alias()]
[OutputType([String])]
Param (
# Param1 Pathvariable
[Parameter(Mandatory=$false, # Change this to $false.
Position=0,
ValueFromPipeline=$true,
ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$true,
ValueFromRemainingArguments=$false, 
ParameterSetName='Parameter Set 1')]
$Path = 'C:\Users\xyc\Desktop\Sheduling\Aufgabe\AccountingData\AccountingList.csv',
$ExportPath = 'C:\Users\xyc\Desktop\Sheduling\Aufgabe\ExportCSV\SortedData\AccountingListSort.csv',
$MultiThread = 'Start-Job'
)



begin {
}

process { 

    $MultiThread | Start-Job -ScriptBlock {
    $ExcludedJobs = @('EndPoint',
    'RecoveryJobNetEndPoint',
    'RecoveryJobNetStartPoint',
    'StartPoint')
    $Accountdata = Get-Content -Path $Path | convertfrom-csv -Delimiter ';' 
    $FilteredData = $Accountdata | Where-Object {$ExcludedJobs -notcontains $_.Jobname} 
    $GroupData = $FilteredData | Group-Object 'AccountNo' | Select-Object @{label='Accountnummer'; expression={$_.Name}}, @{label='Anzahl Jobs'; expression={$_.Count}}
    $GroupData | Export-Csv -path $ExportPath -NoTypeInformation -Delimiter ';'
    }

}


end {
}
```

Comment: Your variables are not present in the job. Use the parameter `-ArgumentList` to make them available.

Comment: Hi, thank you for youre reply. Where do i have to add the parameter -ArgumentList?

Comment: Alright ive got it! The -ArgumentList Param is suppost to be at the end of the scriptblock.